# R loop does not stop

Tags: r, loops

I have a problem that sounds easy, but I really cannot find the mistake. I have 3377 data points (measurements of body temperature). The sampling rate is 5min and I would like to put the data into a matrix. However, R starts recycling once it has put all 3377 data points into the matrix. To prevent r from doing this, I wrote a loop and I want the loop to stop when the end of the vector is reached.

```
 Ankle.r <- 1:3377 # Example data
 a = 288 # sampling rate = 5min -> 288 measurement points per day
 c = 11 # 11 full days of sampling (and a few more points, wherefore the matrix is to be 12 rows)

Ankle.r2 <- matrix(NA, ncol = a, nrow = c+1) # matrix with NAs for 12 days with 288 cols each (=3456 cells)
x <- length (Ankle.r) # total number of data points, is 3377
for (f in 1:(c+1)){   # for each row
  for (p in 1:a){     # for each column (i.e. cell)
    st_op <- (((f-1)*p)+p)  # STOP criterion, gives the number of cells that have already been filled
    if (st_op<x){     # only perform operation if the number of cells filled is < the number of data points (i.e. 3377)
      Ankle.r2[f,p] <- Ankle.r[(((f-1)*p)+p)]
    } else {stop
    }
  }
}
```

However, the loop does not stop...it loops till the last cell in my matrix. According to my calculations, the last 79 cells should remain free (i.e. NA, because 3456 cells - 3377 = 79), but that is only true for the last 8 or so...

Any hints where the mistake is?

Thanks!

Comment: `stop()` is a function that produces an error. If you want to call it, you need the parentheses. I think you're looking for `break` instead, which is used like you tried to use `stop`.

Comment: That said, this is a very hackish work-around. Look for a way that doesn't involve a for loop and a stopping condition.

Comment: Hmm...that may be true. Unfortunately, I find it difficult to come up with a different idea. Do you have any suggestions? Thanks!!

Comment: Sure... try Roland's answer.

Answer (score 3):

I think this does what you would like to do:

```
Ankle.r <- 1:3377 # Example data
a = 288 # sampling rate = 5min -> 288 measurement points per day
c = 11 

length(Ankle.r) <- a * (c + 1) #pad input vector with NA values
m <- matrix(Ankle.r, ncol = a, byrow = TRUE)
```

Answer (score -2):

Ok, try an example and it will show you where your mistake is...*sighing*. The loop must be:

```
 Ankle.r2 <- matrix(NA, ncol = a, nrow = c+1) # matrix with NAs for 12 days with 288 cols each (=3456 cells)
 x <- length (Ankle.r) # total number of data points, is 3377
 for (f in 1:(c+1)){   # for each row
   for (p in 1:a){     # for each column (i.e. cell)
     st_op <- (((f-1)*a)+p)  # STOP criterion, gives the number of cells that have already been filled
     if (st_op<=x){     # only perform operation if the number of cells filled is < the number of data points (i.e. 3377)
       Ankle.r2[f,p] <- Ankle.r[(((f-1)*a)+p)]
     } else {stop
     }
   }
 }
```

Thanks anyway!

Best,
Christine